# Redis Issue Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.redis.core.HashOperations' in your configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis

I am trying to connect to Redis through java, I have following configuration,

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.infy.redisDemo")
public class RedisDemoApplication {

    @Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory getConnectionFactory(){
        LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory = new LettuceConnectionFactory("localhost",6379);
        return lettuceConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String,Object> getRedisTemplate(){
        RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(getConnectionFactory());
        return redisTemplate;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RedisDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

My repo classes :

```
@Repository
public class UserRepoImpl implements UserRepository {

    private RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate;
    private HashOperations hashOperations;

    public final String key = "USER";

    public UserRepoImpl(RedisTemplate redisTemplate,
      HashOperations hashOperations) {
        this.redisTemplate = redisTemplate;
        this.hashOperations = redisTemplate.opsForHash();
    }

    @Override
    public void save(User user) {
        hashOperations.put(key,user.getId(),user);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(User user) {
        hashOperations.put(key,user.getId(),user);
    }

    @Override
    public Map findAll() {
        return hashOperations.entries(key);
    }
}

public interface UserRepository {
    void save(User user);
    void update(User user);
    Map findAll();
}
```

My Controller class as below,

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest/user")
public class RedisController {
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    public RedisController(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/add/{id}/{name}")
    public User add(@PathVariable String id,@PathVariable String name){
        userRepository.save(new User(name,id,25000));
        return userRepository.findById(id);
    }
}
```

When I am running the app I am getting following error,

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'redisController' defined in file [redisDemo\RedisController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepoImpl' defined in file [redisDemo\repository\UserRepoImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.data.redis.core.HashOperations' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

whats wrong in the program ? any suggestion to make it work ? do I need to use  jedisconnectionFactory ? I am using Intellij and my version for **redis is 3.2** on windows and **spring is 2.1.6**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to pass `HashOperations hashOperations` as a parameter in `UserRepoImpl` constructor. Instead you can remove this argument from constructor.

```
public UserRepoImpl(RedisTemplate redisTemplate) {
    this.redisTemplate = redisTemplate;
    this.hashOperations = redisTemplate.opsForHash();
}
```